# How can I access a subversion repository using a local path in Windows?

Tags: windows, svn, command-line

I have CollabNet Subversion server and client installed, running off of Apache that came with it. From the command line on the server, I can easily access the repository using a path like

```
http://server:port/svn/repository
```

but I can't access it using its actual location on the disk, like

```
c:\repositories\repository
```

I just get "[path] is not a working copy." What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: As a note, this question is not specific to Windows and the solutions involving the `file://` protocol can be applied also in GNU/Linux and other Unix-like systems.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Common mistake. You have to use the file:// pseudo-protocol like this:

```
file:///C:/repositories/repository
```

SVN repository paths have to be [URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier)s.

Comment: Keep in mind the three slashes in `file:///`, because putting only two didn't work for me.

Comment: Remember to specify also 'trunk' or the right branch at the end of the full path of the repository, otherwise you'll get too many folders you don't expect :P

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
svn checkout "file:///C|/repositories/repository"
```

and see if you can see the files inside the repo.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use `file:///c:\repositories\repository` to access a repository via path.

Answer (score 0):

Usually "not a working copy" means that there's no .svn "magic subdirectory" there.

You need to do a "checkout" to get a working copy, and not just an "export"

Answer (score 0):

try

> file://c:/repositories/repository