# how to manage a SVN repository using the command line (No URL)

Tags: svn, command-line, command-prompt, database-migration

I'm trying to manage my SVN repository by the command line. This repository has been migrated from an original VSS server. I need to "extract" a working folder from the SVN repository so to compare all the files of every version and check (in this way) that the migration has been correctly completed.

Since I have a lot of folders and repositories, I should create a batch to complete all the operations.

I have read a book about all the commands to use SVN by the prompt line. The problem is that all the commands (as for example "svn checkout" or "svn export") are all referred to the URL of the repository, and I don't have it since I'm not connected to internet, or they are referred to a working copy, and I haven't found any command to create a working copy by the prompt line.
Anyone may help me?

I thank gratefully who ever will answer. :)

Comment: _I haven't found any command to create a working copy_: use `svn checkout`.  You need some sort of URL to connect to your SVN repository, be it `http://`, `file://`, or `svn://`.  Which of these would you use to connect to your repository?

Comment: As I said previously.....I don't use internet to connect to my repository....I have it in a folder in my disk and I use Tortoise and SVN manager to manage it....

Answer (score 3):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1227870/1698557) regarding accessing a local Subversion repository.  In short, if your repository is at C:\path\to\repository, then to get a working copy you'd run [`svn checkout`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.c.checkout.html):

```
> svn checkout file:///C:/path/to/repository
```

This will check out the root of the repository to the current directory.